# Is there a way to use the display preview option in the display block to display the output of wired connections in EV3?

Tags: lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I'm trying to see if there's a way to use the display block in EV3 as a basic print function. I'm working from home and don't have a brick to test the code with so was hoping to just use the display preview option to output variables but I haven't been able to find a way. It will only show the standard 'Wired_1FAC2752-7229-46'. I've tried putting a wait block after it, putting it in a loop and clearing the display first but the preview never displays anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

What about trying a "virtual" brick to run your programm?

Have a look at the "Virtual Robotics Toolkit": https://www.virtualroboticstoolkit.com/

It's not perfect and its not free but maybe a good workaround if you don't have any hardware at Home.

Comment: That is something I had considered. I think I was just hoping for an alternate solution. Cheers